# Why does logging in to Unity session take so long?

Tags: unity, 11.10, login, time

When I'm logging in to Unity in 11.10 it takes about 15-20 seconds for the Desktop to be ready. When I compare that to the loading times of 10.04 where it's almost instant there is a huge discrapancy in log in times. Is gnome3/Unity really that massive to not be loaded faster?

Please no unnecessary comments about:

- *autostart applications* as I set none (at least not by autostart option via cog).
- *bootup-manager* as I reduced the processes there to a minimum

Comment: hardware details?  graphics? memory?  Add these into your question.  Yes unity/gnome-shell are slower that 10.04 - but not 15-20secs on decent hardware.  Have you tried unity-2d to see if this speeds up login?

Comment: it' like that for my two laptops, one of them being very new.
laptop 1: Intel Core 2 Duo T5670, intel onboard graphics, 4gb ram.
laptop 2: Intel Core i5 U520, intel onboard graphics, 4bg ram.
  Thought it's maybe due to checking for update (got a lot of PPAs) and tried to disable it.

Comment: Sure I tried unity-2d, but the log in times are almost the same.

Comment: Does logging in to a system with an encrypted home folder take longer than logging in to a unencrypted one?

Comment: On my box I noticed this is true on initial login or when there were recent changes made, e.g. video driver update, plymouth theme changed, etc. It will take a long time. On subsequent reboots/logins, my Unity is fast. Takes about 5 secs or less to draw the full desktop and I have more than 5 startup apps.

Answer (score 1):

15-20 seconds sounds about right, i got that sort of time when i was using 11.10, since i upgraded to 12.04 (being released tomorrow as of this writing), my login times and boot times have been cut down by about 60%.

In answer to your question, 15-20 seconds is not unusual at all for your hardware, my hardware is comparable to yours but with better graphics.